# Asic Miners adding up?

Tags: mining-profitability

If you were to get multiple miners that do 7.3TH/s do they add up. for example if i had 3 of them would it give me 21.9TH/s? Also What is the coversion rate for TH like how much is 1TH worth in usd?

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate:- [Does mining power of different miners add up in mining pools?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60884/does-mining-power-of-different-miners-add-up-in-mining-pools)

Mining is a lottery, not a race.

The fastest miner doesn't always win. In general, if you have X% of the hashrate, you will find X% of the blocks.

This is because not just all pools, but every every, every chip, ... is attempting to solve a different block proposal. Every attempt has an independent chance of winning. There are an infinite number of potentially valid blocks, but they're still only a tiny fraction of all possible blocks. Everyone is not trying to find the next block - they're trying to find a next block.

So:

Can I add up my hashpower and make it work like a single processor of 1000H/s

Yes. You can't distinguish the different processors - more hashpower just tries more block proposals at the same time.

Both both miners would be acting independently?

Yes. Everything always acts independently.

So this means a mining pool has combined power of all the associated miners and working on one block?

Yes.

All miner are working on different block of their own ??

Yes.

Comment: If you want to get entirely pedantic about it, every once in awhile, two independent processors will both try the same block with the same nonce, (and all other variables), and duplicate work.  So that X hashes + Y hashes will actually only add to (X+Y-epsilon) hashes. (although epsilon will be very small)